# elastic4s: How to automagically read document id into case class instance?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, spray-json, elastic4s

Using `elastic4s 7.12.1` with `spray-json 1.3.6` (and scala `2.13.5`): 
Is there a way to read the `_id` of an Elasticsearch document into a field, e.g . `id`, of a `case class` instance, 
 using only an implicit `spray-json` `RootJsonFormat`, i. e. without wiriting a custom `HitReader` for `elastic4s` and if so, how?
The same goes for writing documents: Is there a way to insert an instance of a `case class` without serializing (making it part of the `_source` in ES) the `id` field using only the aforementioned `RootJsonFormat`, i. e. without writing a custom `Indexable`? 
According to the `elastic4s` documentation, this should be possible using `jackson`, which I want to avoid because of it's numerous critical security issues, that come up all the time.

Consider this case class, which should be indexed into ES:

```scala
case class Foo(id: String, name: String)
```

Using `spray-json`, I would only need to define a `RootJsonFormat`:

```scala
implicit val fooJsonFormat: RootJsonFormat[Foo] = jsonFormat2(Foo)
```

And could use `elastic4s` this way to index and search `Foo`s:

```scala
val someFoo = Foo("idWhichShouldBeOverwrittenByES", "someName")
client.execute {
  indexInto("foos").doc(someFoo)
}

val result: Response[SearchResponse] = client.execute {
      search("foos").query {
        boolQuery().must {
          matchQuery("name", "someName")
        }
      }
    }.await

result match {
        case RequestSuccess(_, _, _, result) => result.to[Foo].foreach(println)
        case RequestFailure(_, _, _, error) => println(error.toString)
      }
```

However, there are major problems with this approach:

- I need to provide an `id` when creating a `Foo`, while I actually want ES to generate the `_id` for me when indexing the document. This is of course primarily caused by using a `case class`
- When loading a `Foo` document, its `id` field contains the (meaningless) dummy value I used when I indexed it, not the actual `_id` under which it's stored inside the ES node

To solve these problems (the first one only partially), I could of course write my own `Indexable` and `HitReader` like this:

```scala
  implicit object FooHitReader extends HitReader[Foo] {
    override def read(hit: Hit): Try[Foo] = Try({
      val source = hit.sourceAsMap
      Foo(
        id = hit.id,
        name = source("name").toString
      )
    })
  }

  implicit object FooIndexable extends Indexable[Foo] {
    override def json(t: Foo): String =
      JsObject(
        "name" -> JsString(t.name),
      ).compactPrint
  }
```

This doesn't look too terrible in a small example, but I think it's obvious that this approach scales horribly, provides no type safety and is a refactoring nightmare, since the names of the fields (e. g. `"name"`) need to be specified manually. 
**Bottomline:** Is there a better a way to achieve a `spring-data-elasticsearch`-like experience or is `elastic4s` with `spray-json` just not suited for this task?

---

**edit:** Another possibility would be to remove the `id` field from `Foo`, introduce a wrapper `case class`, e.g. `FooResultWrapper`, which stores `Foo` search results by `_id` in a `Map[String, Foo]`, use a `RootJsonFormat[Foo]` and `HitReader[FooResultWrapper]` that converts the `_source` to `Foo` and stores it by `hit.id`. But that's also not very satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

Behold the brilliant solution I came up with (basically what I suggested in the edit of the question): 
Removed the `id` fields of my domain `case class` (e. g. `Foo`) and introduced a generic `case class` to wrap the results and force using `objects` to implement `read` from `elastic4s` for the specific `case class`:

```scala
case class ESResultWrapper[T](id: String, result: T)
```

along with a generic `trait`, which contains the implementation for wrapping results of type `T` in `ESResultWrapper` instances:

```scala
trait ESResultWrapperHitReader[T] extends HitReader[ESResultWrapper[T]] {
  def readInternal(hit: Hit)(implicit reader: HitReader[T]): Try[ESResultWrapper[T]] = Try({
    ESResultWrapper(
      id = hit.id,
      result = hit.to[T]
    )
  })
}
```

Now all that's left for actual "domain" classes is to extend the `ESResultWrapperHitReader[T]` `trait` with the specific case class (for which a `RootJsonFormat` also exists) and delegating `hit` to `hitInternal`, thereby implicitly providing a `HitReader[T]` through the `RootJsonFormat[T]`:

```scala
  implicit object FooResultWrapperHitReader extends ESResultWrapperHitReader[Foo] {
    override def read(hit: Hit): Try[ESResultWrapper[Foo]] = readInternal(hit)
  }
```

Usage is pretty simple (sticking with the example from the question):

```scala
result match {
        case RequestSuccess(_, _, _, result) => result.to[ESResultWrapper[Foo]].foreach(println)
        case RequestFailure(_, _, _, error) => println(error.toString)
      }
```

leads to e. g.:
`ESResultWrapper(-XMSQXkB-5ze1JvrVWup,Foo("someFoo"))`

And the best part: Changig the wrapping implementation doesn't impact the domain classes. 
I applaud myself for coming up with this on my 3rd day of using Scala. Good job.